# Createddate compatible format

Tags: date

I am finding the Current date like this .

```
List<Period> LastDatesMonth = [Select type, StartDate, EndDate From Period WHERE type = 'Month' AND StartDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:4 LIMIT 1];

Date EndDateMonthLast = LastDates[0].EndDate;
```

Later in a different SOQL , I want to use

```
 createddate <= :enddate
```

Formats are

```
CreatedDate=2016-05-31 13:07:41
```

and

```
End date 2015-06-30 00:00:00
```

Still why isn't it showing results? [ SOQL is getting saved]

Comment: createdDate is in 2016 and can't be less than 2015, the value in end date. Is your comparison operator correct? should it be `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreatedDate is DateTime, while EndDateMonthLast you have declared as Date. Data type should match.

---

Update: Additional answer to question in comments "how can we get 00:00:00 time":

In the past, I opened two ideas on idea exchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnHPAA0 and https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnP9AAK to make this functionality more intuitive, but for now I have found following workaround: to get 00:00:00 time I use the following snippet of code:

```
Date d = Date.newInstance(2015, 5, 1);
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());
```

Comment: But the formats of both are same , right? As seen in debug logs.

Comment: What Patlatus said was right... You should first check the DataType and Never consider the Format of any datatype in Debug logs with Salesforce Datatype. It might vary....

Comment: I used DateTime dtEndDateMonthLast = datetime.newInstance(EndDateMonthLast, Time.newInstance(00,00,00,00)); - Result : 2015-06-30 07:00:00 . How can I have 00:00:00 time?  Also , it still doesn't match the createddate format ? Please let me know where am I going wrong ?

Comment: @SFDCRookie: In the past, I opened two ideas on idea exchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnHPAA0 and https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnP9AAK to make this functionality more intuitive, but for now I have found following workaround: to get 00:00:00 time I use the following snippet of code:

Date d = Date.newInstance(2015, 5, 1);
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());